# How to move React-JSS styles to separate file?

Tags: reactjs, jss

My colleagues and I have successfully been using React-JSS: https://cssinjs.org/react-jss

However, to date the styles have been embedded in React component files.  As the number of styles have grown, we'd like to move them out into either a `styles.js` or a `styles.css` file (we don't care which).

Trying this so far has not been successful.

Might anyone who has done it, be able to offer some tips?

Comment: can you give us an example of "not successful". Write some code please. Show us what isn't working and how you tried to do it.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you have big files with big/many components and it looks like the amount of styles is the problem.

I would say split your components into separate files and keep styles close to components.

I don't recommend reusing styles without their components, because it leads to leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  I'm working on a deadline tonight so will have to keep this brief.

The current [working] approach works like this: `const styleSheet = { ... }` (with many styles defined where the ellipsis is.

Later on there's a line like this: `const styledComponent = injectSheet(styleSheet)(MyPageName);`

All I want to do is move the `styleSheet` code into a separate `styles.js` file and import it into this current JS file but I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Really late, but create a file with e.g `exampleStyles.js` extension:

```js
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  <Your styles>
});

export default useStyles;
```

Then just import them where ever you want to use them but make sure after importing you declare them before using:

```js
const navbar = () => {
  const classes = <importedStyles()>;

  return (
    <div className={classes.navbar}>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

OMG I don't know why things didn't work earlier today.  I simply put my style code into `styles.js` like this:

```
const styleSheet = {
  mainContainer: {
  height: '100vh',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  backDrop: {
    minHeight: '100vh',
  },
  // ... more styles here
};
```

export default styleSheet;

And then imported it into the React component file with: `import styleSheet from './styles.js';`

It all works great!  Thank you all for the inspiration.